# how to connect to a remote server using ssh and getting the information

Tags: bash, ssh, remote-access

I'm trying to write a shell script using bash. I have multiple servers and each servers have multiple apps runnings on it. Each server also has specific app scripts to check/stop/start etc.  All I want to do is that, do a ssh and connect to the remote server.
Which I'm also able to do sucessfully and exceute the commands also..

In some instance I need to check some process status on a remote machine, the app sepecific scripts already does that. But using my ssh when i try to execute that script I dont get any info ( it gets executed but no info is passed ).  How do i get the information from the remote host and display on the local host here.

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Regards,
Senny

Comment: Please be more specific what do you call *the information* is it the output of the scripts or something else. Did you try to connect via ssh to the remote machine and manually launch the scripts from there? Is it working?

Comment: If you can show what you have tried, someone might be able to tell you why it doesn't work and how to fix it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can [run remote commands and get results locally](http://bashcurescancer.com/run_remote_commands_with_ssh.html) by passing the command as a string to ssh.

In your script, you can do:

```
CMD_OUT=$(ssh user@remote_host "/path/to/script argument")
```

The command will be run remotely and the output store in the `CMD_OUT` variable. You can then parse the output in your script to get the results you want.

To simplify usage of your script, you might want to set up [passwordless ssh](http://everydaylht.com/howtos/system-administration/loggin-in-via-ssh-without-a-password/) so you don't have to type your password each time the script tries to run a remote command.

Comment: I have posted a question here, would you be able to help ? I'm trying to use R / Shiny interface, to submit slurm jobs to a remote HPC, track progress, and view the ouputs from the jobs in shiny.  The shiny app is currently tested locally and eventually would host it as a container on cloud. But, unable to execute HPC specific commands from R. Appreciate any direction on how to achieve
https://community.rstudio.com/t/running-commands-on-remote-hpc-server-via-r-shiny-ui/179989/5